# Separate Nutch regex files to crawl and index to multiple Solr cores

Tags: solr, nutch, solr4

My setup is: Nutch 1.6 and Solr 4.3.0 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

I need to crawl and index the content of a big website and would like doing this using separate cores.

I've configured Solr and started it this way:

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=multicore -jar start.jar
```

Then I configured and launched Nutch two times, one for each source urls folder and index destination (core0, core1):

```
bin/nutch crawl urlsNewsArticles -dir crawlNewsArticles -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/core1 -depth 10 -topN 100000

bin/nutch crawl urlsPictureGalleries -dir crawlPictureGalleries -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/core0 -depth 10 -topN 100000
```

The result is perfect but, in order to filter away undesired URLs patterns, I had to specify some regex expressions in the regex-urlfilter.txt file.
Being those regex sets different for the two crawling sessions, I had to edit the regex-urlfilter.txt file before running the second crawl.

**Question**: is there a way to prepare two separate regex-urlfilter.txt files and specify the proper one on each /bin/nutch command line ?

Please consider that I started my experimental configuration with 2 url sets and cores, but I will have to configure at least 5 and they should be configured for automatic re-crawling without manual editing sessions in between....

Comment: you can try having multiple regex files and the main file as a link and just re pointing it before you start nutch indexing

Comment: Thank you Jayendra, it's a wonderful idea. If you enter it as an answer I will mark it as solved.Cheers, Zander

Comment: thanks .. added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try having multiple regex files and the main file as a link and just re pointing it before you start nutch indexing